# Auto-migration issues with columns in Golang GORM

Tags: postgresql, go, database-migration, psql, go-gorm

Issues with auto migration (i think). I can conclude the column does not exist via psql console. I can insert the column manually via terminal/console/SQL but prefer to resolve this with auto migration.

Thank you for your read and/or action.

TERMINAL OUTPUT:

- Start Web Server: "**(pq: column "password_hash" contains null
  values)**"
- Submit POST: "**(pq: column "password_hash" of relation "accounts" does not exist)**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit: [Jon Calhoun](https://www.calhoun.io/)

Resource: https://www.usegolang.com/

> "...the short answer is that automigrate fails to run because when it adds the column and says it can't have null values this contradicts the fact that any existing records will have a null value by default. The simplest fix since you are still in a dev env is to delete all the users from your table either by dripping the entire table or by running some SQL."

Many thanks to Jon Calhoun for this simple and effective solution.

Comment: I get it, Thank you.